# How to pass params to new view in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make simple app. I input my first name and last name to simple `<%= form_for @data do |f| %>` rails form and after submitting it, app should render simple text like this. `My first name is <%= data.first_name %> and my last name is <%= data.last_name %>`. I don't know why but my app is saying this error:

> undefined local variable or method `data' for

It's probably saying it because no params are passed to view.

Here is my code.

routes.rb

```
resources :data, only: [:new, :create, :index]
```

data_controller.rb

```
class DataController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @data = Data.new
  end

  def index
  end

  def create
    @data = Data.new(data_params) 

    if @data.valid?
      redirect_to @data
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def data_params
      params.require(:data).permit(:first_name, :second_name)
    end
end
```

/views/data/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @data do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

    <%= f.label :second_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :second_name %>

    <%= f.submit 'Continue', class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

/views/data/index.html.erb

```
<h2>Coolest app ever :D</h2>
<p>My first name is: <%= data.first_name %>.</p>
<p>And my second name is: <%= data.second_name %>.</p>
```

/models/data.rb

```
class Data
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :first_name, :second_name

  validates :first_name, :second_name, presence: true 
end
```

Please help to find out why params are not passing to next page. Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should look like this:

```
<h2>Coolest app ever :D</h2>
<p>My first name is: <%= @data.first_name %>.</p>
<p>And my second name is: <%= @data.second_name %>.</p>
```

Also, I would suggest that calling a model something generic like `Data` is not a very Rails-y approach. Generally, domain models correspond to real-world things like `User` and `Article`, which are easy to understand and relate to. It'll get confusing quite fast if you use need to make another model and want to call it `Data2` or something :)

Comment: still showing the same `undefined method first_name for nil:NilClass` error. And in error log i see no params are passed to that page.

Comment: Your `index.html.erb` file lists all of the things in the database. If you have not created any yet, then you will get this error.

Comment: How can i do it without creating database. Please see last file, I just added it to question.

Comment: Without the database, you will need to create the `@data` object in the `index` controller action somehow. At the moment, it is empty. The default Rails thing is to create a record in the database in the `create` action, then redirect to the `show` page so you can see it. You currently do not have this action in your controller, so the `redirect_to @data` line in your `create` action will throw an error. I would recommend running the Rails scaffold generator, then looking at how the generated code works. This way you can see how things look when they work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

Since you specified that you do not wish to use the database, I would recommend passing in the object params through the redirect:

```
redirect_to(data_path(data: @data))
```

and in your controller's index method:

```
def index
  @data = Data.new(params[:data])
end
```

Now your view should render properly, since you're passing the in-memory `@data` object attributes as params within the redirect. You then recreate this object in the index page or wherever you wish to redirect to.

---

To expand on Matt's answer, the reason you're getting NilClass errors is because:

You're redirecting to a `data#show` action when no `show` action has been enabled within your routes file. Since you've set your views up for the index, I'm assuming you want to redirect there when the @data object has been verified as valid:

```
redirect_to data_path
```

However I would recommend you follow Rails conventions and specify the `data#show` route within your routes.rb:

```
resources :data, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show]
```

and in your data_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @data = Data.find(params[:id])
end
```

Another problem is that you're not actually *saving* the `@data` object upon creating it. The `new` method populates the attributes, and `valid?` runs all the validations within the specified context of your defined model and returns true if no errors are found, false otherwise. You want to do something like:

```
def create
  @data = Data.new(data_params) 

  if @data.save
    redirect_to data_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Using `save` attempts to save the record to the database, and runs a validation check anyways - if validation fails the save command will return false, the record will not be saved, and the `new` template will be re-rendered. If it is saved properly, the controller will redirect to the index page, where you can call upon the particular data object you want and display it within your view.

Comment: Can it be done without saving to database? it would make everything more complex and i don't want to save it. Idea is to use data only once. Maybe there is a way.

Comment: Just updated my answer, you should be able to pass in the in-memory @data variable to the redirect method and then build another in-memory object in your index action or wherever you wish to redirect to. Hope it helps!.

Comment: don't know why but its not working. Params are not passed to index page.

Comment: still no params passed to index page.